# Creating SharePoint List (Form) which is Dynamic - preceeding choice determines next set of questions

Tags: javascript, forms, list, dynamic, sharepoint-2010

I am attempting to create a list in sharepoint 2010 (which is serving a form that a user can fill out). However, I am attempting to make it dynamic such that:

Question 1 (or technically, column 1 in the list): YES/NO question.
IF NO, display Questions 2-15 (or technically, columns 2-15).
IF YES, display another set of questions, let's call them Questions 16-18 (only 3).

So, it would be dynamic based only on this first question. I want only this first yes/no question to appear when the user attemps to 'add a new item' to the list. Then, once they answer this first question, it would make the new set of questions appear based on this first questions response.

I am taking the route of doing this via JavaScript. So far, I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function()
{
$('td.ms-formlabel:contains("Title")').parent().hide();
$('td.ms-formlabel:contains("Start Time")').parent().hide();
$('td.ms-formlabel:contains("End Time")').parent().hide();
});
</script>
```

This is just a test script I've been using. Basically just using a smaller number of fields to test on a test list I'm using in SharePoint to get the hang of how I want this form to be, so that's why you only see 3 columns so far in the code.

So far, the code I've been playing with is just hiding fields (which I have assumed needs to be done because in the beginning, I want all the questions to be hidden except question 1, right? At least that's how I'm thinking about it and I'm sure you guys know better than me).

So, I'm thinking hide all except that first question. Then I should add an IF STATEMENT, basically saying IF NO, display questions ABC. IF YES, display questions XYZ. However, I'm stuck on how to do this. I'm a total beginner in programming but I've been trying to google and do my best to learn.

Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you!!

P.S.
People have said InfoPath is an option. I don't have InfoPath and this route won't be an option for me.
People have said it might be possible to do this using Content Types. I haven't looked into this option just yet.

Comment: Have you tried using Survey list template? It allows branching logic.

Comment: Hi. No I have not, but I was just reading into it just now. I see that in a survey list template, there is a "jump to" option that can seemingly accomplish what I am trying to do. I think. I will play around with it and revert back; if this works without having to do javascript, that would be excellent.

Comment: "revert" means to "go back to a previous state", not "to reply or get back to a person". So you can put a spoiler on your car then "revert" to the standard body, but you can't take a car for a test drive then "revert" to the salesman that you will buy the car :P

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with lists: [Implement Cascading Dropdowns](http://jassimkhan.blogspot.com/2010/10/implement-cascading-dropdown-in.html)

Either way, I would use the sharepoint template as user1985793 said or the javascript cascading dropdowns plugin.

EDIT:

**Your app would look like this**

Question 1: select box - yes or no shown

Question 2: select box - populates choices on question 1 selection

Question 3: select box - populates choices on question 2 selection

**You would then make 3 lists. One list for each question.**

1st list:
yes or no

2nd list: all possible choices with "parent" column set to a 1st list name

3rd list: all possible choices with "parent" column set to a 2nd list name

Comment: Hi. I just read over the cascading dropdowns article. However, I am confused: how can this help me to accomplish my goals? Perhaps I am not fully understanding. Would you mind clarifying the concept of the cascading dropdowns in relation to my specific task?

Comment: explained the answer more fully.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for updating your response. I've been trying to play around with it for the past 2 hours now... My set up so far:
List 1: NewRequest (This list contains all the questions that should come up if the user selects no on the first question)
List 2: TEST (This list contains only two entries: Existing and New)
List 3: Yes (This list contains one item: "Is this a new request?")

I've set up the 'look up' on List 3 (Yes), which refers back to List 2 (Test). I see that the drop down menu is now synced over... but I still am not understanding fully how this is going to help me @rhythmedium

Comment: Then I go back to 1st list (NewRequest) and set up another custom look-up column pointing back to List 3 (Yes). So now, when this 1st list is opening, it does have the drop down from List 2 asking the question that I want: Is it a new request? But it's not really set up how I want it to be? I'm not sure... I must be doing something entirely wrong. But I'm definitely on the brink of something.

Comment: sorry to bother - any help?